# How to convert an image from input to json, send it in fetch to php and then send it on server via PHPMailer?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch, phpmailer

I'm not very good in PHP and all server stuff, so I would appreciate any answers and advice.

I need to send JSON data and an image in one fetch to php script.

Following this question [How can I serialize an input File object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/how-can-i-serialize-an-input-file-object-to-json), I made object from image, put it in fetch and tried to send this object in PHPMailer as an attachment, but I've got this error:

```
[Sun Jan 24 15:07:52 2021] 127.0.0.1:59260 [500]: POST /dist/php/mail.php - Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/dist/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:3005
```

So, my JavaScript code:

```
 // firstly, declaration of variables
let files, 
    fileObject,
    newObject,
    myArray = [];
// when user uploads image with input, code makes new src for <img> tag with this image
form.onchange = (event) => {
 image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    
 image.onload = () => {
// on load of image I give new values to variables, and make an object with info from an image
 files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
 fileObject = files[0];
 newObject  = {
  'lastModified'     : fileObject.lastModified,
  'lastModifiedDate' : fileObject.lastModifiedDate,
  'name'             : fileObject.name,
  'size'             : fileObject.size,
  'type'             : fileObject.type
    };  
   }
  }
// And here's the fetch :)
  fetch(`${server}/dist/php/mail.php`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'preferences': purchase, // this is usual object 
      'jsonObject': newObject, // and this is an image object
    })
  });
```

And here's the mail.php code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
send_mail('pansfloyd@gmail.com', 'joe brock', $data);

function send_mail($email, $name, $data) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "dealinmaivasha@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password"; //changed this :D
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->From = "dealinmaivasha@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Dealin Maivasha";

    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Subject Text";

    $mail->addAttachment($data->jsonObject); // SO, this is where I need to send image, and this line doesn't work at all
    $mail->Body = "Body";
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

So, the question is, how can I change line with addAttachment so it all would work?

Just in case, I tried to use console.log to see what is in newObject, here's the result:
[result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1yhZ.png)

As you see, I also got an error in console.

I also tried to use myArray variable in js like that:

```
  myArray.push(newObject)
```

And then I tried to send myArray in fetch, but it didn't work either.

I would be very grateful to any answers and recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [the source for the `addAttachment` method of `PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/fa9c13cefdc9349c045fd13603533f61474984ed/src/PHPMailer.php#L2979). (Pasted to the end of this answer.)

You're passing an object (`$data-> jsonObject`) where the method expects a string corresponding to a file path.

The solution could take many forms - you've got to find some way to take the submitted data and save at least a temporary file to the server before sending it as an attachment via PHPMailer.

You're already sending the rest of the data in a `Content-type: application/json` format, but following some of the approaches in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997961/file-attachment-with-phpmailer) which uses an `enctype` of `multipart/form-data` on the form could be one way.

Alternatively, you might [convert the image's data to base64 and POST it with the rest of your JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926893/sending-an-image-and-json-data-to-server-using-ajax-post-request). Then, on the other side, [decode & save to `/tmp/{filename}.ext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string) and reference THAT as the first arg to `$mail->addAttachment`.

```
/**
 * Add an attachment from a path on the filesystem.
 * Never use a user-supplied path to a file!
 * Returns false if the file could not be found or read.
 * Explicitly *does not* support passing URLs; PHPMailer is not an HTTP client.
 * If you need to do that, fetch the resource yourself and pass it in via a local file or string.
 *
 * @param string $path        Path to the attachment
 * @param string $name        Overrides the attachment name
 * @param string $encoding    File encoding (see $Encoding)
 * @param string $type        MIME type, e.g. `image/jpeg`; determined automatically from $path if not specified
 * @param string $disposition Disposition to use
 *
 * @throws Exception
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function addAttachment(
    $path,
    $name = '',
    $encoding = self::ENCODING_BASE64,
    $type = '',
    $disposition = 'attachment'
) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Much simpler – send it as raw JSON data by using the `addStringAttachment()` method.